# Azure application insights: EventCounterCollectionModule enable/disable on demand

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

On a production asp net core webapp, we wanted to collect System.Runtime counters (cpu-usage,gen-0-size,gen-1-size etc) using EventCounterCollectionModule and push it to azure application insights.

We wanted to enable and disable this module(EventCounterCollectionModule) programmatically. As far as documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core)is concerned, this can be done only during the ConfigureServices method of StartUp class during IServiceCollection service registrations. So this requires re-deployment for enabling and disabling the logs.

Is there a way to enable or disable the Module in the code(ex : controllers) except startup.cs ConfigureServices method.

Comment: As of now "this can be done only during the ConfigureServices method of Startup class during IServiceCollection service registrations". You can refer to [Using Application Insights to collect EventCounterCollectionModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/eventcounters). You can open an issue on GitHub: [ApplicationInsights-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT I will raise an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to change the config "on the fly" is not there for ApplicationInsights currently.